# Guarantees on sizeof(int) in Single UNIX or POSIX

Tags: unix, posix, sizeof

What are the size guarantees on `int` in Single UNIX or POSIX? This sure is a FAQ, but I can't find the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C99 standard specifies the content of header `<limits.h>` in the following way :

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude
>   (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> - minimum value for an object of type int
>         `INT_MIN -32767` // -(2<sup>15</sup> - 1)
> - maximum value for an object of type int
>         `INT_MAX +32767` // 2<sup>15</sup> - 1
> - maximum value for an object of type unsigned int
>         `UINT_MAX 65535` // 2<sup>16</sup> - 1

There are no size requirements expressed on the `int` type.

However, the `<stdint.h>` header offer the additional *exact-width integer types* `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` and their unsigned counterpart :

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a
>   signed integer type with width N, no
>   padding bits, and a two’s complement
>   representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes a
>   signed integer type with **a width of
>   exactly 8 bits**.

Comment: Well by that definition, `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short) >= sizeof(int16_t)` is the guarantee.

Comment: And `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @user502515, @Jonathan: absolutely, I just meant in my answer that there is no "absolute" size requirement (ie: `int` must be *n* bytes)

Answer (score 4):

With icecrime's answer, and a bit further searching on my side, I got a complete picture:

ANSI C and C99 both mandate that INT_MAX be at least +32767 (i.e. 2^15-1). POSIX doesn't go beyong that. Single Unix v1 has the same guarantee, while Single Unix v2 states that the minimum acceptable value is 2 147 483 647 (i.e. 2^31-1).

Comment: Where's the requirement that `INT_MAX >= 0x7FFFFFFF`? I can't find it in the IEEE 1003.1-2008 spec for `stdint.h` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Comment: It's on the page for `limits.h`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html

Comment: The phrase "POSIX doesn't go beyong that." (sic!) can be quite misleading. The base definition (XBD) from IEEE Std 1003.1-2004 aka POSIX 2004 onward specifies ints to be at least 32 bits (derived from `WORD_BIT` as can bee seen in the link above).

Answer (score -1):

POSIX doesn't cover that.  The ISO C standard guarantees that types will be able to handle at least a certain range of values but not that they'll be of a particular size.

The `<stdint.h>` header introduced with C99 will get you access to types like `int16_t` that do.

Comment: POSIX covers it by way of ISO C.

Comment: POSIX includes `stdint.h` explicitly and expands on its definition in ISO C. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html